# ENOENT error when running 'npm install' in AWS Amplify: Unable to find package.json file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-amplify

I'm trying to publish a very simple express project with AWS Amplify. I'm fairly new to this process and it's my first time using AWS in general, I get the impression it can't find the package.json file but I have this in my root folder.

Here is the error log:

```
# Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm install
2023-05-30T08:09:29.775Z [WARNING]: npm
2023-05-30T08:09:29.776Z [WARNING]: ERR! code ENOENT
                                    npm ERR! syscall open
2023-05-30T08:09:29.776Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! path /codebuild/output/src268349047/src/project-name/package.json
2023-05-30T08:09:29.776Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! errno
2023-05-30T08:09:29.776Z [WARNING]: -2
2023-05-30T08:09:29.777Z [WARNING]: npm
2023-05-30T08:09:29.777Z [WARNING]: ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src268349047/src/project-name/package.json'
                                    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
                                    npm ERR! enoent
2023-05-30T08:09:29.778Z [WARNING]: 
2023-05-30T08:09:29.778Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                                    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-05-30T08_09_27_691Z-debug-0.log
2023-05-30T08:09:29.782Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-05-30T08:09:29.782Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
```

Here is the amplify.yml build settings file:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        # Execute pre-build commands if necessary
        - amplify init
        - npm install
        - npm i aws-sdk cors dotenv express
    build:
      commands:
        # Execute build commands if necessary
        - amplifyPush --simple
    postBuild:
      commands:
        # Execute post-build commands if necessary
        - npm start   # Start the Express server
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: /public
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "project.title",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon --watch app.js"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-ses": "^3.338.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1385.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```

My file structure looks like this:

[image]

Any help much appreciated, thanks in advance!